# New to jQuery. Issues with jQuery part of code?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, pug

I have a simple chat room using express, node, and jade. I want to add a function so that when I press enter, I send a message. But when I start the server and press enter, it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#field").keyup(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });
});
```

Also, here is my jade file:

```
doctype
html
    head
        title= "Real time web chat"
        script(src='/chat.js')
        script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
        script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js')
    body
        #content(style='width: 500px; height: 300px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; border: solid 1px #999; overflow-y: scroll;')
        .controls
            | Name: 
            input#name(style='width:350px;')
            br
            input#field(style='width:350px;')
            input#send(type='button', value='send')
```

Help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You should add your html as well so we can make sure your #field if is a valid element for what your trying to do.

Comment: input#field(style='width:350px;')

Comment: Are you able to create a basic JS Fiddle using jade which for now just throws an alert?

Comment: I was following a tutorial. Here is the link: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708